# probability that sum of geometric random variables is odd

Tags: probability, self-learning

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent geometric random variables with the same parameter $p$. What is the probability that $X+Y$ is odd?

Based on the provided solutions, I can follow through until this part which confuses me:

$$P(A) = \sum_{k = 2,\ k\; \text{even}}^\infty \;p(1-p)^{k-1} 
= p\sum_{i=1\; }^\infty (1-p)^{2i-1} $$

My question:

1) The lower summation bound states *k=2 and k even*. I do not understand why this is necessary ? if k is starting at 2 then k is automatically even, no?

See full solution below:

[image]

Comment: If $k$ starts at $2$, then the next term would correspond to $k = 3$, which is odd. So *no*, it is not implicit that $k$ is even just because $k = 2$.

Comment: The condition on $k$ is badly written.   The "even" isn't meant to just apply to $k=2$. You want the sum over all **even** $k$ from $2$ to $\infty$.  A better notation might be $\sum_{k \in 2 \mathbb N}$ where $\mathbb N$ is the positive integers.

Comment: makes sense, thanks